# How to pass values between two pages using Razor in Webmatrix?

Tags: razor, webmatrix

I am new to Razor and Webmatrix.I was trying to pass values using POST method from one page to another page but i am not able pass values. I have googled on it but didn't get any solutions. So can any one provide me the guidance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you having difficulties with? On one page you create a `<form>`:

```
<form action="/foo.cshtml" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="bar" value="" />
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
```

and on the other page you read values from the request: `Request["bar"]`:

```
@{
    var bar = Request["bar"];
}
```

Comment: thanx man....my problem is solved....and one more question is that if actions are different and i want to get data using Response.Redirect then what should i have have to so?

Comment: @Stark, Response.Redirect means GET request. So you will need to pass values at the query string: `Response.Redirect("/foo.cshtml?bar=baz");`. At the target page you could access it the same way from the Request object.

Answer (score -1):

A typical way to do it if both pages are in the same project:

1. Post the form to a specific controller.
2. Using the controller arguments, pass the data to the view model of the other page, and render the View

Comment: There are no such things as Controllers in WebMatrix.

Comment: i assumed hes using the MVC framework with Razor as the view engine in the webmatrix